# Ubuntu 12.04 VPS SSH not running, how to reset SSH configuration files?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

Yesterday after I re - enabled root user and rebooted the VPS, now SSH and SFTP are not running. FTP working.  I can only connect this VPS via VPS provider web based console.

When I run "ssh restart" command in VPS provider console it shows "19 bad configuration option" in "ssh_config" file. But i didn't do anything like that. However that bad configuration option are similar to the default config file.

So how do i reset the ssh_config file without loosing anything? If i reinstall open SSH it will reset the ssh_config file to the default.

Comment: `ssh_config` is for your ssh **client**. The server configuration is in `sshd_config`.

Comment: paste configuration... maybe some one will tell you what is wrong and will correct your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to first uninstall openssh completely. You can do this by running

apt-get remove --purge openssh-server

then install and see if all works.

Comment: Yes it's working.